# regex optional word

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regex that will match each of the following cases from a set of `ldap objectclass` definitions - they're just strings really.

The variations in the syntax are tripping my regex up and I don't seem to be able to find a balance between the greedy nature of the match and the optional word "MAY".

```
( class1-OID NAME 'class1' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST description MAY ( brand $ details $ role ) )
```

DESIRED OUTPUT: description 
ACTUAL GROUP1: description 
ACTUAL GROUP1 with ? on the MAY group: description MAY

```
( class2-OID NAME 'class2' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST groupname MAY description )
```

DESIRED OUTPUT: groupname
 
ACTUAL GROUP1: groupname 
ACTUAL GROUP1 with ? on the MAY group: groupname MAY description

```
( class3-OID NAME 'class3' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( code $ name ) )
```

DESIRED OUTPUT: code $ name
ACTUAL GROUP1: **no match**
ACTUAL GROUP1 with ? on the MAY group: code $ name

```
( class4-OID NAME 'class4' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( code $ name ) MAY ( group $ description ) )
```

DESIRED OUTPUT: code $ name
ACTUAL GROUP1: code $ name
ACTUAL GROUP1 with ? on the MAY group: code $ name

Using this:

`MUST \(?([\w\$\-\s]+)\)?\s*(?:MAY)` ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nrBjqR/1))

matches lines 1, 2 and 4, but doesn't match the 3rd one with no `MAY` statement.
Adding an optional "?" to the `MAY` group results in a good match for 3 and 4, but then the 1st and 2nd lines act greedily and run on into `MAY` (line 1) or the remainder of the string (line 2).

It feels like I need the regex to consider `MAY` as optional but also that if `MAY` is found it should stop - I don't seem to be able to find that balance.

Comment: Are you using PCRE? Try `MUST\s+(?|\(([^()]+)\)|(\S+))\s*(?:MAY)?`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4YKQej/2).

Comment: Or, do you just need `\bMUST\s+(?:(?!MAY).)*`? [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4YKQej/3)?

Comment: Or is `MUST\s+(?:\([^()]*\)|\S+)(?:\s+MAY)?` enough? [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4YKQej/4)

Comment: Can you perhaps add an expected output? Sometimes it's easier to think of something on one's own than base the answer on asker's trials on solving the issue.

Comment: Please, specify language/tool

Comment: Wiktor - that first pattern is the one - matches nicely for all cases, but I'm not using PCRE. I'm using IBM JS regex, but it's an older version (not something I can control).  Altering your pattern to MUST\s+(?:\(([^()]+)\)|(\S+))\s*(?:MAY)? pretty much solves it.  The only issue is that because it uses alternatives it produces output into different capture groups.  Not a huge issue because this isn't a generic function & only intended for these LDAP syntaxes which have minimal variation.

Comment: @KarlP Next time please prepend usernames with `@` to let them know of your feedback. I posted an answer below.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - sorry - typo - mis-clicked the auto-complete & mangled the name string.  Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can use a regex with two capturing groups you may use

```
MUST\s+(?:\(([^()]+)\)|(\S+))\s*(?:MAY)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4YKQej/5)

**Details**

- `MUST` - a word `MUST`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:\(([^()]+)\)|(\S+))` - two alternatives:

  - `\(` - `(`
  - `([^()]+)` - Group 1: 1+ chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - a `)` char
  - `|` - or
  - `(\S+)` - Group 2: one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:MAY)?` - an optional word `MAY`